# MATLAB: image corner coordinates & referncing to cell arrays

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cell-array

I am having some problems comparing the elements in different cell arrays.

The context of this problem is that I am using the `bwboundaries` function in MATLAB to trace the outline of an image. The image is of a structural cross section and I am trying to find if there is continuity throughout the section (i.e. there is only one outline produced by the `bwboundaries` command).

Having done this and found where the is more than one section traced (i.e. it is not continuous), I have used the `cornermetric` command to find the corners of each section.

The code I have is:

```
%% Define the structural section as a binary matrix (Image is an I-section with the web broken)
bw(20:40,50:150) = 1;
bw(160:180,50:150) = 1;
bw(20:60,95:105) = 1;
bw(140:180,95:105) = 1;

Trace = bw;
[B] = bwboundaries(Trace,'noholes'); %Traces the outer boundary of each section

L = length(B); % Finds number of boundaries
if L > 1
    disp('Multiple boundaries') % States whether more than one boundary found
end

%% Obtain perimeter coordinates
for k=1:length(B) %For all the boundaries
    perim = B{k}; %Obtains perimeter coordinates (as a 2D matrix) from the cell array
end

%% Find the corner positions
C = cornermetric(bw);

Areacorners = find(C == max(max(C))) % Finds the corner coordinates of each boundary

[rowindexcorners,colindexcorners] = ind2sub(size(Newgeometry),Areacorners)
% Convert corner coordinate indexes into subcripts, to give x & y coordinates (i.e. the same format as B gives)

%% Put these corner coordinates into a cell array
Cornerscellarray = cell(length(rowindexcorners),1); % Initialises cell array of zeros
for i =1:numel(rowindexcorners)
    Cornerscellarray(i) = {[rowindexcorners(i) colindexcorners(i)]};
    %Assigns the corner indicies into the cell array
    %This is done so the cell arrays can be compared
end

for k=1:length(B) %For all the boundaries found
    perim = B{k}; %Obtains coordinates for each perimeter
    Z = perim; % Initialise the matrix containing the perimeter corners

    Sectioncellmatrix = cell(length(rowindexcorners),1);
    for i =1:length(perim)
        Sectioncellmatrix(i) = {[perim(i,1) perim(i,2)]};
    end

    for i = 1:length(perim)
        if Sectioncellmatrix(i) ~= Cornerscellarray
            Sectioncellmatrix(i) = [];
            %Gets rid of the elements that are not corners, but keeps them associated with the relevent section
        end
    end
end
```

This creates an error in the last for loop. Is there a way I can check whether each cell of the array (containing an x and y coordinate) is equal to any pair of coordinates in *cornercellarray*? I know it is possible with matrices to compare whether a certain element matches any of the elements in another matrix. I want to be able to do the same here, but for the pair of coordinates within the cell array.

The reason I don't just use the *cornercellarray* cell array itself, is because this lists all the corner coordinates and does not associate them with a specific traced boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many-to-many comparisons cannot be done with the equal sign. You need to use ismember instead.

```
%# catenate all corners in one big corner array
Cornerscellarray = cat(1,Cornerscellarray{:});

%# loop through each section cell and remove all that is not corners
for i = 1:length(perim)
     %# check for corners
     cornerIdx = ismember(Sectioncellmatrix{i},Cornerscellarray,'rows');

     %# only keep good entries
     Sectioncellmatrix{i} = Sectioncellmatrix{i}(cornerIdx,:);
end
```

Also, this code really looks like it could be a bit optimized. For example, you could use bwlabel to label your arrays, read the label with the corner coordinates to associate corners with the features.

Like so:

```
bw(20:40,50:150) = 1;
bw(160:180,50:150) = 1;
bw(20:60,95:105) = 1;
bw(140:180,95:105) = 1;

%# get corners
cornerProbability = cornermetric(bw);
cornerIdx = find(cornerProbability==max(cornerProbability(:)));

%# Label the image. bwlabel puts 1 for the first feature, 2 for the second, etc.
%# Since concave corners are placed just outside the feature, grow the features 
%# a little before labeling
bw2 = imdilate(bw,ones(3));
labeledImage = bwlabel(bw2);

%# read the feature number associated with the corner
cornerLabels = labeledImage(cornerIdx);

%# find all corners that are associated with feature 1
corners_1 = cornerIdx(cornerLabels==1);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats really helpful, I wasn't aware of the bwlabel function before.

Comment: @James: That's one of the nice things about Matlab: Because of the many functions and toolboxes, you can get away with very little typing even for complex operations.